# Python Requests: What fields append to the url

Tags: python, get, python-requests

So I am using python Requests( http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to work with a REST api. My question is when using Requests what data field actually appends info to the url for GET requests? I wasn't sure if if I could use "payload" or if "params" does it.

Comment: partially off topic: check command line tool called [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) which is based on `requests`, is perfect replacement to curl and wget and is very well suited for REST testing.

Comment: cool, I use postman alot to do testing too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in the docs:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

> As an example, if you wanted to pass key1=value1 and key2=value2 to
>   httpbin.org/get, you would use the following code:
>
> `payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}`
>
> `r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)`

After all - you can of course easily test it, in case you're simply not sure which of two choices is the proper one.
As the example shows, http://httpbin.org (a site by the `requests` author) is a nice way to test any web programming you're doing.

Comment: While your answer is correct, providing a "link as an answer" is not welcomed in SO. The reason for that is, in case the link gets stale - there's no "real" answer left. Either copy the relevant paragraph from the link and add it to your answer or post it as a comment.

Comment: @alfasin You're probably right - guess I meant to leave some minimal work for the OP...

Comment: Now you're getting my +1 as well ;)